# Can i move items from a custom list to another list after a specific retention?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, policy, retention

I wanted to move items from a custom list in SharePoint 2013 with content type "item" to another list after a specific period (retention expiration). But the transfer to another location involving drop off library supports document libraries only. Please suggest any alternatives to implement this. Thanks

Comment: You can use a Workflow with a delay action.

Answer (score 0):

I would either recommend a workflow which is kicked off when the item is added to the list and as Max said have a delayed action, or some sort of wait until the retention date before processing the move. Things to be careful of is the retention date needs to be set in the future otherwise the move will process almost immediately, how you deal with the retention date changing.

Alternatively you could write a custom timer job which would go through all the items and check the retention date and if it is in the past move the file programmatically. The problem with this version is there is going to be a delay depending on how often you run the timer job.

Cheers

Truez

Answer (score 0):

Drop off library is the default destination, in order to change this go to

Site Settings > Content Organizer Rules

Then create a new Rule specifying your Content type and finally Target Location choose your new custom destination that can support your specific content type